# Is it possible to get the Saitek X45 working with Windows 8.1 64bit?

Tags: hardware, windows-8.1

I have an old Saitek X45 HOTAS:

[image: Saitek X45]

Are there drivers that will let it work with my Windows 8 computer? Google is not helping!

Comment: There are no 64-bit drivers for this device.  It only supports 32-bit operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

The official Saitek FTP site has a download at:

ftp://ftp.saitek.com/pub/software/x45/x45_151205_64.exe

I suggest trying that, though I'm afraid I don't have this device so can't verify if it works. However, other Saitek devices I've used on 64 bit OS's with drivers from here have worked well.

Comment: Might be a good idea to link to the [folder](ftp://ftp.saitek.com/pub/software/x45/) just in case they update the driver version (extremely unlikely but you never know).

Comment: These don't work on windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

ftp://ftp.saitek.com/pub/software/full/Saitek_X45_Flight_Controller_SD6_64.exe

I had better luck with that install then with the other one linked to on the ftp site. It appears to have installed fine on my windows 8.1 x64

There's also a x86 driver as well 
ftp://ftp.saitek.com/pub/software/full/Saitek_X45_Flight_Controller_SD6_32.exe

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled my Saitek X45 out of cold storage and dusted it off (8/19/18). I installed the 64-bit drivers and the Profiler/Profile Editor software pack on my HP laptop running Win10 (SP 4/18).

The Profiler/Profile Editor software pack allows you to identify and calibrate your controls. So far everything is running fine. Gonna try them out on War Thunder and see how things go. Good Gaming!

Here's the link for Saitek's driver page including the X45:

http://www.saitek.com/uk/down/drivers.php